# How to add multiple pdata identities of same type to one sample, and be able to distinguish by those identities when plotting

Tags: r, seurat

I am trying to essentially add phenotypic information (pdata) to a sample in this dataset.

```
library(BiocManager)
library(GEOquery) 
library(plyr)
library(dplyr) 
library(Matrix) 
library(Seurat) 

# Loading Raw Data into RStudio ---------------------------------- 
    
    filePaths = getGEOSuppFiles("GSE118389") 
    tarF <- list.files(path = "./GSE118389/", pattern = "*.tar", full.names = TRUE) 
    untar(tarF, exdir = "./GSE118389/") 
    gzipF <- list.files(path = "./GSE118389/", pattern = "*.gz", full.names = TRUE) 
    ldply(.data = gzipF, .fun = gunzip) 
    
    list.files(path = "./GSE118389/", full.names = TRUE)
```

I load in the sample information for say, patient 39 (PT039), in the following manner:

```
# Load in full matrix ----------------------------------------------------------

fullmat <- read.table(file = './GSE118389//GSE118389_counts_rsem.txt', 
                      sep = '\t', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# Load in PT039 matrix -----------------------------------------------------------
PT039mat <- grep(pattern =c("^PT039") , x = colnames(fullmat), value = TRUE)
PT039mat = fullmat[,grepl(c("^PT039"),colnames(fullmat))]
PT039mat[1:5,1:5]
```

I then add the associated pdata in the following manner, essentially creating a separate dataframe aside from `PT039mat` which will later be added on as the pdata into the Seurat object:

```
PT039pdat <- data.frame("samples" = colnames(PT039mat), 
                        "lymphovascular_invasion" = "no", 
                        "nodal_involvement" = "no",
                        "BRCA_status" = "BRCA-")
```

This creates the following:
[image: Output of pdata]

I may be thinking about this the wrong way, but I have the following information, with PT039 present in multiple batches. I want to essentially recreate this exact dataframe into `PT039pdat`:

```
Batch   Patient ID
B1        PT039 
B2        PT058
B3        PT039, PT081, PT089
B4        PT081
B5        PT084, PT089
B6        PT084, PT089
B7        PT126
B8        PT039, PT084
B9        PT039
```

I can do exactly this using the following code:

```
PT039_batch <- list(c("B1", "B3", "B8", "B9"))
PT039pdat$batch <- PT039_batch
```

[image: Output of adding batches]

But when I try to plot the different batches on a UMAP, it isn't able to detect the separate possibilities, if that makes sense.

```
DimPlot(sobj, reduction = "umap", split.by = "batch")

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , split.by, value = c(PT039_P11_A01_S1 = "B1",  : 
  replacement has 3538 rows, data has 1325
```

I want to be able to create this, but with batches information split by B1, B2, B3, etc.
[image: What want, but split by batches]

Sorry for the long question, but thank you for reading!

Comment: what you are doing doesn't make much sense. do you know which rows (or cells) in your metadata correspond to which batch?

Comment: I don't :( the paper (https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-06052-0) only gave this information

Comment: I really can't read the paper to find the information of the batch.. I see that on the names of the sample, there is a P11 or P07 etc if this is the batch you just need to pull that out no?

Comment: Hello again @StupidWolf! I am not sure what you exactly mean by "pulling out the batch information"

Comment: ok how did you get this information `PT039_batch <- list(c("B1", "B3", "B8", "B9"))` ? is there somewhere in the paper that states what this might be. Otherwise it's not going to work. Sorry I am not so familiar with this field

Comment: No worries @StupidWolf! (you are not actually stupid lol) It was in their supplementary files - I copied the batch information they provided in my question (the two column table with Batch and Patient ID). I basically need help with adding values under a column in a dataframe in such a way that it can be plotted by batch (B1, B3, etc.) without having to create separate columns for each possibility (e.g.) PT039 could have, if that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/issues/4650 . It looks like I need the batch information for each cell if I want to plot it in the way that I am.